# Why is my Selenium web-scraping code breaking at the line obtaining the number of rows?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, button, while-loop

I'm relatively new to the world of coding and scraping. I need to scrape this website for a work assignment collecting information about the athletes: https://www.worldaquatics.com/athletes?gender=&discipline=&nationality=&name=.

Using many links on stack overflow, I was able to cobble together some code using Python and Selenium. Without the while-loop, everything works fine. Once the while-loop is going, it will sometimes get stuck (ie, stop responding), but I can get it to reach the end and print "complete" as indicated in the code.

The big question I have is why the code is breaking at the line obtaining the number of rows?

I tried adding in wait times and reformatting the loop per some suggestions online. The most common error after reformatting would be Element is not clickable at point (X,Y). Using the method I have now, I don't hit this error. I suspect that the while loop is not correct but I don't understand/see what is wrong.

Thank you for your help and suggestions ahead of time.

```
while True:
    try:
        # Load more button path
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/section/div[2]/button')
        # Scroll down to button location
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
        # Click on button 
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        break
print ("Complete")

#Obtain the number of rows in body
rows = 1+len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/section/div[1]/table/tbody/tr'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More lightweight approach than using `selenium` would be using their pagination Ajax API and load the data from this call directly:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

ajax_url = "https://api.worldaquatics.com/fina/athletes"

params = {
    "gender": "",
    "discipline": "",
    "nationality": "",
    "name": "",
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
}

data = []
for params['page'] in range(4):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    print(f"{params['page']=}")
    data.extend(requests.get(ajax_url, params=params).json()['content'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head(10))
```

Prints:

```
        id                            providerId                 firstName                    fullName nationality gender disciplines metadata  lastName dateOfBirth  height
0  1074444  2c6c1bd5-c9ae-4243-a831-cd01c3d76dba                                                               TUR      M        [SW]       {}       NaN         NaN     NaN
1  1307409  ea73f88c-2e02-43c4-a0af-d2d84e7e5368      Tanish George Mathew      Tanish George Mathew -         IND      M        [SW]       {}         -  2003-10-09   179.0
2  1028294  df3cdee9-42d7-4204-bbea-bac0fe6bdc06          Md Yaqoob Saleem          Md Yaqoob Saleem -         IND      M        [SW]       {}         -  1998-03-11   148.0
3  1666771  b92df120-b865-4bf6-b90a-75f065afb078               Saba Suhana               Saba Suhana -         IND      F    [SW, OW]       {}         -  2008-08-07     NaN
4  1666800  d3d25f7e-dbc7-4859-89a4-056cd3b9db44  Bangalore Mahesh Rithika  Bangalore Mahesh Rithika -         IND      F        [OW]       {}         -  2007-06-25     NaN
5  1044546  f2beac3b-9f86-4e2b-a06d-7de6574ffa5a                      Anna                Anna AAGAARD         DEN      F        [SW]       {}   AAGAARD         NaN     NaN
6  1032095  0e97c40b-d11f-4b77-a4cb-7624d6386df6                     Cathy              Cathy AALBERTS         NED      F        [SY]       {}  AALBERTS  1997-01-01     NaN
7  1160243  56a63091-9817-4703-98a6-adafc3dd5134          Einari Ferdinand      Einari Ferdinand AALTO         FIN      M        [SW]       {}     AALTO  1926-05-27     NaN
8  1166191  edb8088f-8252-4256-8067-72b5accacaed                    Oskari                Oskari AALTO         FIN      M        [SW]       {}     AALTO  2002-05-26     NaN
9  1020046  c17b8c43-31fd-4985-8ee2-70aa80dccd0e                      Sami               Sami AALTOMAA         FIN      M        [SW]       {}  AALTOMAA  1992-08-07   190.0

...
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrej Kesely. How do I manage the range value if I don't know how many pages there are in total?

Comment: @SmudgedGlasses You can use `while True:` loop and increase the page parameter in each iteration. Just break from the loop when you get empty or error response from the server.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I will try this later today and hope it works. I appreciate the speedy response.